# Android SIGSEGV error with array

Tags: android, pointers, java-native-interface, segmentation-fault, native-code

I've problem with native code in Android.

I used this code to fill array with content from vector

```
float * Map_Loader::ConvertToArray()
{
    float *arr = new float[(faces.size() -1)*3];
    int index = 0, j = 0;
    while(index < faces.size())
    {
        arr[ j ] = faces[ index ].vertex[ 0 ].x;
        arr[ j +1 ] = faces[ index ].vertex[ 1 ].y;
        arr[ j +2 ] = faces[ index ].vertex[ 2 ].z;
        j += 3;
        index++;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

and I used this code to create pointer and get values from the function:

```
float *x = Map.ConvertToArray();
```

It's working in windows , but in android I've problem..

Best regards

Comment: Why do you only allocate space for `(faces.size() - 1) * 3` floats? Your loop looks like it attempts to copy `faces.size() * 3` floats.

Comment: Thanks Michael ,  good comment ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it !!

The answer code must be like this :

```
float *x;
x = Map.ConvertToArray();
```

thanks everybody ;)